# How can one replace a Lori branded lock that won't fit in a new door

Tags: doors, lock

I've replaced an exterior door on my house and the old deadbolt won't fit in the new door because the back set is different.

The deadbolt key is common to all my exterior doors, and I'd like to be able use the same key with the new door.

#### About The Old Lock

The lock may be original to the house which was constructed in 1989. The brand *Lori* is also associated with *Ilco*, *Kaba*, and *US* locks. The lock cylinder is a mortise style cylinder. The diameter of the notches is 1" and the diameter of the threads is about 1.14". The deadbolt assembly appears to be model *4512-05 S/C US5*. I'm only able to find 2" backsets but I need 2-3/4".

[image: Installed lock]

[image: Diagram]

[image: Mortise Cylinder]

[image: Diameter]

[image: Depth]

The Keyway is KW1 and there are 5 pins.

How can I find a deadbolt that uses the same key as my other locks but fits in this door?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a lot of trouble finding information on this lock and I'm pretty sure this style is not as common as I've never encountered it before. When I realized that my key for it was a Kwikset keyway, I determined that it is the same keyway used on the user rekeyable smartkey locks so I ordered a Kwikset 980 (~$25) and was able to re-key it to the Lori key.

#### Your results may vary

I called Kwikset support to ask if I'd be able to use a non-kwikset key (although it is a Kwikset KW1 keyway) on the smart lock. I was told it may or may not work and they guy had never heard of Lori locks.

In this case, I'm happy it worked.

[image: installed qwikset]